# Calculation in jQuery form

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a form with a short calculation to figure out frame sizes for bikes.

The calculation is: length * 0.68 = frame size. However, if the option of saddle pin is selected, there should be a deduction of 4 (of the calculated frame size).

This is what I have so far:

```
$("select[name='length']").change(function(){
    var $l = $('length[name='length']');
    if($l.length >140){
        var m = parseInt($l.val(), 10)
        $("#result").val(l*0.68);
    } else {
        $("p").text("Hello world!");
    }     
});
```

---

```
<form>
    <input type="text" value"" name="length">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="nopin"> Zadelpen
    <input type="text" value="" id="result"/>
</form>
<p></p>
```

And the fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/m2qnf3jm/

As you can see it's not giving me any result. I am new to jQuery and tried to follow the tutorials I could find on this subject. My guess is I need a button to 'start' the calculation? And how do I deduct at the end if the option saddle pin is selected?

There also is a minimum length of 140, so I tried to echo something if someone puts in a value lower than that.

Comment: The issue is `$('length[name='length']');` with the selector (*length is not an element*) and the quotes  `''`. And check consolefor errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html and javascript lot typo and invalid syntax. Try this:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('input[name="length"]').on('change', function() {
    var lengVal = $(this).val();
    var m = parseFloat(lengVal) * 0.68;
    
    $('#result').val(lengVal > 140 ? m : 'Hello World!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" value="" name="length">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="nopin"> Zadelpen
<input type="text" value="" id="result"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will evaluate what went wrong. However, I don't get the last rule, what does 14 ? m do? And I'm trying to show the calculation in the box, not the 'hello world'. The html output is for when someone inputs anything smaller than 140.

Comment: @Kelly It's a shorthand If statement. When lengVal > 140 is true, it will pick the expression to the left of the " : " , otherwise it will take the expression to the right of the semicolon. So it does what you asked, when the input is <= 140, it will us "hello word!"

Comment: Ah I understand now! Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad to help you.. anyway, If you think this is helped you, please mark as answer. So other people can use this too. And, point for me too :P

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#cacl_btn').on('click',function() {
$("p").text('');
  var $l = $('input[name="length"]').val();
   
  if ( $l >= 140) {
    var m = $l * 0.68;
var deduction=$('input[name="type"]').prop('checked')?4:0;
   $("#result").val(Math.round(m*100)/100-deduction);
  
  } else {
    $("p").text("length couldn't be <140");
      $("#result").val('');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" value "" name="length">
  <input type="checkbox" name="type"> Zadelpen
 
  <input type="button" id="cacl_btn" value="calculate">
   <input type="text" value="" id="result" />
</form>
<p></p>
```

If i understand your calculations correct , try to run this code

Also,in your fiddle you forgot to add link to jquery

I also advise you to use id for inputs or class names.

Answer (score 1):

The **onchange** event seems a little askew.

```
$().ready(function () {
    //PAGE READY FUNCTION - THE PLACE TO BIND EVENTS
    $("input[name='length']").on('change, keyup', function () {
        var length = $(this).val();
        if($l.length >140)
        {
            var m = parseFloat(length);
            var value = m * 0.68;
            $('p').html("NORMAL");
            if($('#radio_button').is(':checked'))
            {
                value = value - 4;
                $('p').html("ZANDELPEN");
            }
            $("#result").val(l*0.68);
        } 
        else     
        {
            $("p").text("Too Short!");
        }
        });

});
```

## EDIT

Too late it seems. But the radio button code is there for you.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('[name="length"]').on('change', function(){
        var l = $(this).val();
        if(l > 140){
            $("#result").val(parseInt(l) * 0.68);
        }
        else{
            $("p").text("Hello world!");
        }
    });
});
```